# In which $L^p$ metric is $\pi = 3.5$?

Tags: metric-spaces, lp-spaces, pi

In which $L^p$ metric is $\pi = 3.5$? I am interested because it's well known that $\pi$ can range from $3.14...$ to $4$ in $L^{\infty}$

Comment: This $p$ probably cannot be expressed in any nice way.

Comment: Isn't it $2\sqrt 2\approx 2.82$ in the $L^1$ norm?

Comment: Woops. Sorry, I'll fix it.

Comment: There is a nice and helpful question exists: [$\pi$ in arbitrary metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254620/pi-in-arbitrary-metric-spaces).

Comment: Looks like @Wojowu is right - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/264312/33079) for the decidedly non-nice expression to solve

Comment: @Wauzl I believe it isn't - the unit circle has circumference $2\sqrt{2}$ when measured using Euclidean distances, but taxicab-length of that circumference is $4$.

Comment: The fast search leads to $5.01797$ for $p$. Not sure if it's possible to have exact expression.

Comment: @Wojuwu: You seem to be right. This messes with my mind though :)

Comment: Are you interested in a numerical approximation? Because i think it would be too hard to find a closed expression

Comment: Not really, but out of curiosity how are they done?