# Generating $p$-norm circles

Tags: circles, lp-spaces, pi

I came across this post from 2016 and am curious about something one of the answers called "opaque". Unfortunately, that member appears to be inactive.

[Measuring $\pi$ with alternate distance metrics (p-norm).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044223/measuring-pi-with-alternate-distance-metrics-p-norm/2053651#2053651)

The question is about computing $\pi$ for $l_p$ spaces. Heres the part of Zach's answer I'm interested in:

> The p=2 is the only p-norm that has the SO(3) Lie Group structure. In
> other words, it is rotation invariant. Try it, you can rotate the
> coordinate system without changing the length. You can't do that with
> the Taxicab metric, the length you get will change.
>
> The deep answer to your question is that only p=2 has a continuous
> symmetry, rotation. All the other p-norms have a either a finite
> number of symmetries or symmetries. Here's the thing, a p-unit circle
> is something like every possible vector that can generated from the
> group glued together. Imagine starting with a small vector then
> copying and rotating it just a bit, attaching it to the original
> vector, then repeating with the copy. Eventually, you'll generate the
> circle. **You generate any of the p-norm circles using a similar process
> using their symmetry, albeit a bit more opaque**. So why is p=2
> special? The circle is made with the shortest vectors, and only the
> shortest vectors available to construct it. Why? Because they're all
> the same length! This isn't true unless you're rotationally invariant
> and guess what? Only p=2 is!!

I thought about this before and figured there was nothing. Don't all $l_p$ circles (for $1\le p<2$ or $p>2$), have the symmetry of a square? So, I see how we could generate circles for $p=1,2,\infty$, but no more.

$p=1,\infty$ seem ambiguous to me, so I'm not particular how they work out. For $p=2$, Zach appears to be saying something like $\int_\gamma x|dx|\approx \gamma$ where $\gamma$ is an positive arc of the unit circle starting at $(1,0)$ and $\approx$ means homothetic. At least, if you rotate a vector repeatedly by a small positive amount then add all the resultants together in a path, you will have a circular envelope.[[image: a way to generate the <span class=]$l_2$ circle from the symmetry of the $l_2$ circle" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK3oX.png)

To answer the question, you would need to provide a generalization of this aspect of $l_2$ to all values of $p$ for $1<p<2$.

Comment: I was hoping someone could explain "generate any of the p-norm circles using a similar process using their symmetry," i.e. the opaque bit. I've edited the OP to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Why did I suddenly lose 120 in reputation for this question?